# query IG Media api return Unsupported get request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I have created different API queries on searching hashtags and searching recent media with that. This all works fine. but when I grab the ID from media objects from the recent_media query and try to query them separately since then I'm able to query more data. It won't work.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/ig_hashtag_search?access_token={token}&user_id={user_id}&q=stackoverflow`

This returns

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "17843780662045901"
        }
    ]
```

Then I query

`https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/17843780662045901/recent_media?access_token={token}&user_id={user_id}&fields=id,media_url`

with result

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "17939405797365335"
        },
        {
            "id": "17868693508835640"
        },
```

and then I try to access media

`https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/17939405797365335?access_token={access_token}&user_id={user_id}&fields=username`

I get

```
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17939405797365335' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AkgnyCLvXaH430A6Rji4Ju0"
    }
```

User has the following permissions:

```
        'instagram_basic',
        'pages_show_list',
        'pages_read_engagement'
```

I also tried other fields instead of the username. but nothing works. seems everything should be right . rechecked the docs 100 times.

Comment: facing the same issue, would be great to know if you were able to resolve this

Comment: Same problem here, according to the docs it should work. Did someone fix that?

Comment: Same here. I noticed though that it works for the media owned by the IG user whose access token is used in the request, so I assume it's some sort of restriction to access other's media, although not explicitly mentioned in the docs..

Comment: this is still an issue

Answer (score 0):

As following documentation, we don't have permission to access other user's media objects directly.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery?locale=en_US

> You can use both nested requests and field expansion to get public
> fields for a Business or Creator Account's media objects. Note that
> this does not grant you permission to access media objects directly —
> performing a GET on any returned IG Media will fail due to
> insufficient permissions.